# What's wrong with my replacement GFCI outlet?

Tags: gfci

I'm trying to replace a GFCI outlet in my bathroom.  (the old one trips almost every time you plug something in)  When I connect the line wires from the panel to the line poles and the load wires to the load poles, I get no power light (the little LED light) on the outlet and it won't reset.  However, if I connect the line wires to the load poles, the power light comes on, but it still won't reset.  To add to my confusion, if I put the old GFCI back in place, everything works fine.  What am I doing wrong?  I think I've done everything but purposely cross-wiring...

Comment: Read the documentation that came with the device. Some GFCI's have a light that's on when they have power, other only have a light when they trip.

Comment: Also, try wiring it in without connecting the LOAD side at all. There might be a fault downstream. And that may be why it trips when you plug something in.